# How to pass custom Data to jquery Mobile Dialog from initiated Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having three Link in a page. Each Link having different custom data attribute with different value. Each Link opens same Dialog when clicked.

```
<a data-custom="My Val1"  href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true">Link 1</a>

<a data-custom="My Val2"  href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true">Link 2</a>

<a data-custom="My Val3"  href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true">Link 3</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content">
  <!-- Custom data -->
</div>
```

I want to have custom data value available to Dialog from the Link which was clicked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ApjLB/

Comment: @Omar Just out of curiosity: What's the difference between jqmData() and data()?

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jqmData/ its recommended to be used when using jQM. Both function the same.

Comment: Thaks it seems working.